# How to add a segment of code in a Python File from commandline with sed command?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line

I have a python code like this :

```
a=10
b=20

if(a==b):
    print("a=b")
else:
    print("a!=b")
```

Now I have to modify the script and add some lines to it from command line using sed. After modifying it should look like this :

```
    a=10
    b=20

    if(a==b):
        print("a=b")
        print("This Line is added")
        print("Another Line added")
    else:
        print("a!=b")
```

How to add those 2 lines which include new line and how to maintain proper indentation of Python syntax.

Comment: What is condition to add new lines ? After `print("a=b")` line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to add new lines after `print("a=b")` line. First create a file `add.txt` and add your lines which you want with proper indent alignment. Then,

```
sed '/print("a=b")/r add.txt' file
```

Comment: Any way to auto detect the indent ? as the main code will be written by some one else, so I don't know what he will be using space or tab :(. My main problem is with the indentation only.